# I got strange error in Laravel migration base view/table not found 1146

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I did migrate from laravel with this migration file

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class MsCustomer extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('mscustomer', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
$table->increments("custid");
            $table->string("custname");
            $table->string("password");
            $table->string("email")->unique();
            $table->integer("balance");
            $table->string("role");
            $table->timestamps();

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('mscustomer');
    }

}
```

and then it succeeded, a table with name 'mscustomer' was made in my database, and then I tried to use php artisan tinker by calling a model which is mscustomer.php, it contains

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class mscustomer extends Model {


}
```

then I get this error
"Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'twk.mscustomers' doesn't exist......"

what I can't understand it, I clearly created mscustomer, but why does it look for "twk.mscustomers" (with 's') behind, not twk.mscustomer. Is there any mistake did I do in this case?

please help me.

Note: sorry for the bad style of asking question, this is the very first time ever I ask a question here.

Answer (score 1):

That's just how Laravel works. Eloquent will assume the plural of the model class name as table name. You can override this behavior by adding a property:

```
class mscustomer extends Model {
    protected $table = 'mscustomer';
}
```

---

Besides that it's also pretty standard to use class names that start with a capital letter. In your case `Mscustomer` (or maybe `MsCustomer`) instead of `mscustomer`